# What happened to the colours?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, color-scheme

The colour of hyperlinks on the main site changed today. While basic links remain blue, they turn orange on hover, and a darker orange-brown colour when visited:

[image: screenshot of the main site questions page]

I can’t imagine this awful colour scheme to be intentional. Since links are orange on the meta site, I suspect some CSS confusion.

Comment: This also affects some other sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344292/why-are-the-colors-of-visited-and-non-visited-links-on-academia-se-so-different

Comment: I *knew it*!!!!

Comment: This is now reported as fixed; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344301/147362.

Comment: Also, I don’t want to make a post about it, but hasn’t MathJax recently stopped displaying when pages [update](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_2.0#Technologies) to announce [new activity](//i.stack.imgur.com/mqXUW.png) and you [click](//i.stack.imgur.com/TEL01.png)? Only after [reloading](//i.stack.imgur.com/v6edN.png) does the math display for me. (On up-to-date Firefox & Safari, caches emptied, etc.)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Something similar was reported on [math.meta.se]: [Mathjax stops rendering after clicking “An edit has been made to this post”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30568). The question is marked ([meta-tag:status-review]).

Comment: Oh. 15+ people confirming. Now for us I think it started far less than 6 months ago. Maybe that can help them pinpoint the change that caused this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed. An explanation is given in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344301.